# Dealing with a leading NA when using na.locf to fill string NA's

Tags: r, string, list, for-loop, na

## EDIT:

Please note that the problem in this question was simply that I accidentally put `zoo::na.locf(l[[i]][1], na.rm=TRUE)`, when it should be `zoo::na.locf(l[[i]][1], na.rm=FALSE)`. However by the time I figured this out the question had already received two answers. As a result, instead of removing the question (as this is discouraged after people have submitted answers), I have slightly adapted the question, to make sure the post will at least have some merit.

## Question:

I have a list of dataframes:

```
test_dat <- structure(list(...5 = c("euro", "euro", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "dollar", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

test_dat2 <- structure(list(...5 = c(NA, "euro", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "dollar", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

test_dat2
# A tibble: 9 × 1
  ...5  
  <chr> 
1 NA    
2 euro  
3 NA    
4 NA    
5 NA    
6 NA    
7 NA    
8 dollar
9 NA    

l = list(test_dat , test_dat2)
```

I want to fill `NA`'s in the list of df's, but sometimes there is a leading `NA`. I do not know for which entries there is leading `NA`.

```
for (i in seq_along(l)){
  # Fill first column
  l[[i]][1] <- zoo::na.locf(l[[i]][1])
}
```

Leading to:

```
Error:
! Assigned data `zoo::na.locf(l[[i]][1])` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 9 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 8 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I assumed that the following would solve it, but did not:

```
for (i in seq_along(l)){
  # Fill first column
  l[[i]][1] <- zoo::na.locf(l[[i]][1], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Desired output:

```
test_dat2
# A tibble: 9 × 1
  ...5  
  <chr> 
1 NA    
2 euro  
3 euro
4 euro
5 euro
6 euro
7 euro
8 dollar
9 dollar
```

Comment: @Maël No, I am just a bit of an idiot. They should be normal `NA`. I will correct it.

Comment: You explicitly say that you want to use a `for` loop for this, is there a reason? The canonical (and fastest and perhaps easiest to read) would be something like `lapply(l, function(l1) { l1[[1]] <- zoo::na.locf(l1[[1]], na.rm = FALSE); l1; })`.

Comment: Also, your desired output is the second data, not `l`, are you intending your operation to replace `NA`s in both `l` and `test_dat2` at the same time?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your comments. The reason for the for-loop request, was that I have a whole sequence of mutations written in a for-loop. I thought it would be easier to stick that. In hindsight, maybe an apply function is much better. I only showed the data from `test_dat2` because only there I run into an issue. I thought showing all data would clutter the question. Looking at your data I actually noticed that the only mistake I made is to put `na.rm=TRUE`. I will remove the for-loop request (as that is already fixed now), and simply accept the best answer. My apologies for the chaos.

Comment: When you say `na.rm=TRUE` doesn't work. What do you mean?

Comment: @sindri_baldur See above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem with R 4.2.1, zoo 1.8.11, dplyr 1.0.10 and tibble 3.1.8. The code in the question with `na.rm=FALSE` works for me as do any of the lines below.  Make sure that you have the latest version of all packages and R and restart R and try the code in the Note below and then the code in the body of this response with a fresh instance of R.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

l <- l.orig
for(i in seq_along(l)) l[[i]][1] <- na.locf(l[[i]][1], na.rm = FALSE)

l <- l.orig
for(i in seq_along(l)) l[[i]][, 1] <- na.locf(l[[i]][, 1], na.rm = FALSE)

l <- l.orig
for(i in seq_along(l)) l[[i]][[1]] <- na.locf(l[[i]][[1]], na.rm = FALSE)

l <- l.orig
lapply(l, function(x) replace(x, 1, na.locf(x[, 1], na.rm = FALSE)))
```

If each component of `l` has only one column (which is the case in the `l` shown in the question) a simplification is possible.

```
l <- l.orig
for(i in seq_along(l)) l[[i]] <- na.locf(l[[i]], na.rm = FALSE)

l <- l.orig
lapply(l, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE)
```

If the data frames have the same number of rows  we could represent `l` as a data frame and apply `na.locf` to it assuming it is ok to apply `na.locf` to all columns.

```
l <- l.orig
DF <- data.frame(l)
na.locf(DF, na.rm = FALSE)
```

### Note

```
library(dplyr)

l.orig <-
list(structure(list(...5 = c("euro", "euro", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "dollar", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(...5 = c(NA, "euro", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "dollar", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this. I assume you want to apply this across both dataframes in the list.

```r
library(tidyverse)


l |>
  map(~fill(.x, everything(), .direction = "down"))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   ...5  
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 euro  
#> 2 euro  
#> 3 euro  
#> 4 euro  
#> 5 euro  
#> 6 euro  
#> 7 euro  
#> 8 dollar
#> 9 dollar
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   ...5  
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 <NA>  
#> 2 euro  
#> 3 euro  
#> 4 euro  
#> 5 euro  
#> 6 euro  
#> 7 euro  
#> 8 dollar
#> 9 dollar
```